# slack github integration doesn't find wiki repository

Tags: github, integration, bots, wiki, slack

I'm trying to add a GitHub slack integration (https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS2SX-github) that will post whenever a change is made to our repository's GitHub wiki. I can log in to GitHub just fine and I see my repositories, but I don't see the repository for the wiki. The wiki is an actual repository; I can clone it and view its history and everything. For example, if my repository were called myRepo, the wiki would be myRepo.wiki. But I only see myRepo in the list of repositories the integration can watch.

I've tried adding an integration that watches myRepo. It successfully messages the channel I selected whenever somebody pushes changes to myRepo, but it doesn't do so whenever changes are made to the wiki. I'm guessing that's because they really are two separate repositories.

Is there a way to get the GitHub integration to be able to watch the repository for the wiki?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you have the webhook set to notify on just the push event.

You may also need to select Let me select individual events.  and make sure

```
"Gollum
Wiki page updated."
```

Is checked

Comment: Thanks for the response, though I'm actually talking about the github slack app (https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS2SX-github), not webhooks.
I've been having other issues getting github's webhooks to work with slack.

Comment: Ahh - I can't load that app (firewall plus our corporate version of slack) so thought it might be part of same thing.  
Though you might want to check to see if it might have put a webhook on your repo under the hood, it could do so via the API I think (I'd check but I can't access the app :) )

Comment: Hm... that's a good question. I'll check. In the meantime, I posted another question detailing my other webhook related woes, if you're interested in taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080513/slack-doesnt-recognize-github-webhook-payload-format

Comment: You were right. A webhook was created under the hood, and I could go in and make sure that Gollum was checked. Unfortunately, while I can see that doing so does cause a payload to be generated whenever the wiki is updated, I never see those updates appear in slack. Though everything else does appear (code pushes, pull requests, etc.) Bummer. I'll keep poking around. Thanks for the idea though.